# Export a 1D list in Python in one column

Tags: python

When i want to export a list in a txt file it displays the elements in one line instead i want each elements in one column. For instance this list:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I want to export it in a txt file so that my file contains in one column the elements of the list:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With one list:

```py
with open('my_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(str(x) for x in my_list))
```

---

WIth two lists:

```py
with open('my_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    to_write = ""
    for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)):
        to_write += f'{a},{b}\n' if i < len(list1) - 1 else  f'{a},{b}'
    f.write(to_write)
```

Comment: Good answer. The square brackets are redundant though.

Comment: Hi, thanks. And if i want to do the operation for 2 lists i can't do
 f.write('\n'.join(str(x) for x in my_list)+ '\n'.join(str(x) for x in my_list2) )

Comment: @Haswellrefresh2 - updated with solution for two lists

Comment: after testing it, w mode doesn't really work instead one should use the append mode "a" to work it properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
fname = "myfile.txt"
num_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

# open the file
with open(fname,"w") as fw:
   # Iterate through the elements, minus the last one
   for num in num_list[:-1]:
      # Write the number as a string, the concatenate a new line
      fw.write(str(num)+"\n")
   fw.write(str(num_list[-1]))
```

Comment: This adds a new line at the end in the last line.

Comment: Now you've forgotten brackets at the end.